# Component renders before waiting for API Response in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, promise, components, vue-directives

I have created two components that depending on a API Response will render either of one of the two components.

- When the **`Promise`** doesn't resolve or the **`Promise`** resolves, but it sends an empty **`object`** it renders an error, notification card message.
- When the **`Promise`** resolves, it renders the data list component holding the data response.

Now, I got it working properly. However, I have a small bug. The error, notification component renders for half a second when there is data on the response. Then, it disappears and the data list renders. Obviously, the component won't wait for the **`Promise`** to evaluate.

Is there a way I could prevent the rendering of the component until the **`Promise`** is evaluated? Or could you offer me other solutions?

**Component that renders the data:**

```js
<ReferralsList
      ref="referralList"
      v-if="mainSource"
      :service-id="serviceId"
      :source="mainSource"
/>
```

**Component that displays the error message:**

```js
<Card v-else>
  <template slot="card-content">
    <InlineNotification type="DANGER">
      {{
        The Client Intake module currently does not have any configured referral source.
      }}
    </InlineNotification>
  </template>
</Card>
```

**`Promise` Data:**

```js
created() {
  this.getReferralsSources({ service_id: this.serviceId })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
        this.sourcesList = res.body;
        this.mainSource = Object.keys(this.sourcesList)[0];
        this.loading_sources = false;
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      const message = this.$t('Could not load referrals.');
      this.notifyError(message);
    });
},
```

Comment: You can use your `loading_sources` variable and `v-if`

Comment: I tried this & it just reverse the issue now & renders list data component for half a second & render the wrong component after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `v-if` together with `v-else` handles exactly 2 states. But you are working with 3 states - loading, loaded with no error, error while loading. Unless you change your template to handle 3rd state (loading) explicitly, one of the other two will be rendered during loading (empty list or false-positive error message component)

Solution:

1. introduce 2 state variables in your data - `isLoading: false` and `error: null`
2. Before you start loading your data, set `isLoading= true` and `error = null`
3. If error on loading, set `isLoading= false`, `error = ...error`
4. If loading succeeds set `isLoading= false, error = null`
5. Use following template:

```
<Card v-if="error">
 ...show error here
</Card>
<p v-else-if="isLoading">Loading...</p>
<ReferralsList v-else>
</ReferralsList>
```

Or if you don't need the exact "error" state (not a good idea IMHO):

```
<p v-if="isLoading">Loading...</p>
<ReferralsList v-else-if="mainSource">
</ReferralsList>
<Card v-else>
 ...Some static error message
</Card>
```

...same logic as above, just set `mainSource` to null every time before you start loading

There is a [great 3rd party component](https://github.com/posva/vue-promised) handling exactly this in a very nice way...

Comment: This is a very good solution, but unfortunately I can't add third state. I'm pretty sure it won't be accept once my code is review before merging. Is there any way to wait for the Promise to evaluate and put hold on the rendering?

Comment: To represent 3 states you only need 2 state variables. I'v used state variables `isLoading` and `error` (+ `mainSource` to store data) but you can of course use `isLoading` and `mainSource` together - you just loose the error message....

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `showReferralsList: false` in your data. And then in your then-clause set it to true:

```
if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
    this.sourcesList = res.body;
    this.mainSource = Object.keys(this.sourcesList)[0];
    this.showReferralsList = true;
    this.loading_sources = false;
}
```

And your ReferralsList-component to `v-if="mainSource && showReferralsList"`

Hope this helps!